# How can I put a Dynamically updated variable in a docked cell (e.g. toolbar)

Tags: front-end, dynamic, docked-cell

I have made a toolbar that does things that are particularly useful for me. I like the fact than it is always visible at the top of the notebook, just like a ... toolbar. I want to put some dynamically  updated values in the toolbar so I can see where I am in some processing job in/on the toolbar.  I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Here is the code I use to make the toolbar:

```
cell := SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell];
selected := NotebookSelection[SelectedNotebook[]]; 
sn := SelectedNotebook[]; 
SO = SetOptions;
gray = Lighter[Gray, .8];
datestring := DateString[{"MonthShort", "/", "Day", "/", "YearShort"}];
timestring :=  
DateString[{"MonthNameShort", "\[VeryThinSpace]", "Day", 
"\[VeryThinSpace]", "Year", "\[VeryThinSpace]", "Hour24", ":", 
"Minute"}];
fsz = 14;
fete = FrontEndTokenExecute;
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
  Grid[{{
     Button[
      Style["Quit", FontFamily -> "Arial", fsz, 
       FontColor -> White], 
      FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[sn, "EvaluatorQuit", Automatic]], 
      Background -> Red],
     Button[
      Style["Delete Output", FontFamily -> "Arial", fsz, 
       FontColor -> White], 
      FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[sn, "DeleteGeneratedCells", 
        Automatic]], Background -> Red],
     Button[
      Style["Edit Stylesheet", FontFamily -> "Arial", fsz, 
       FontColor -> White], 
      FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[sn, "Edit Stylesheet...", 
        Automatic]], Background -> Red],
     Button[
      Style["Font", FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting", fsz], 
      fete[(*sn[],*)"FontPanel"], Background -> gray],
     Button[Style["Clear", FontFamily -> "Arial", fsz], cell; 
      fete[sn[], "ClearCellOptions"], Background -> gray],
     Button[Style[Dynamic[n], FontFamily -> "Arial", fsz], 
      Background -> White],
     }}, Spacings -> {.06, 1}]]],
"DockedCell", Background -> None]];
```

Changing "n" outside of the toolbar seems to work.  I wonder if it works because I'm  using the 11.2 beta?

Comment: I think you would greatly improve your chances of answer if you reduced your example to docked cell that shows one quantity that need dynamic updating plus it minimal supporting code and explained why it doesn't work. As your question now stands I am unable to find the values you say you can't dynamically update in your code.

Comment: Oh. There isn't a dynamic cell there.  I added the code to show how  I made the toolbar.  Should I simplify it?

Comment: In the process of creating a simplyfied example, I may have solved my problem.  This new code seems to work.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe if the question is not valid anymore maybe there is no point for it to stay?

Comment: Perhaps someone might look for the question and be helped by the  answer?